# attachtment image not showing on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to show images of featured post image but does not appear

```
<?php 
 $url = wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($post_id, 'thumbnail_size'));
?>
```

Comment: Try using `echo` before the `$url` variable..

Comment: Are you getting valid post id? Why not simply use global variable `$post` you can get post id `$post->ID`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show the Featured Image of a particular post, Please use following code.

```
<?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ): ?>
   <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ),                                                         
       'single-post-thumbnail' ); ?>
    <div id="custom-bg" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $image[0]; ?>')">
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Where `$post` is global post variable :-

```
$url = wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID));

echo $url;
```